# How to create a function that fills tow DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

I m creating a small database application in which I have to fill tow DataGridView
Named “DG1” and “DG2” using the flowing  function:

```
private SQLiteDataAdapter DB;
    private DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    private DataTable DT = new DataTable();

    public void LoadData(DataGridView Grid, String fields, String table)
    {
        SetConnection();
        sql_con.Open();
        sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
        string CommandText = "select " + fields + " from " + table;
        DB = new SQLiteDataAdapter(CommandText, sql_con);
        DS.Reset();
        DB.Fill(DS);
        DT = DS.Tables[0];
        Grid.DataSource = DT;
        sql_con.Close();
    }
```

After calling it in the main form

```
LoadData(DG1, "*", "CLIENTS");
```

the first grid will fill up just fine but when I call the second method

```
LoadData(DG2, "*", "COURSES");
```

the first client DataGridView is empty and the  second DataGridView is filled with correct information

Comment: You are using DG1 for both calls.

Comment: First Time use table zero (DT = DS.Tables[0];) Second time use table one (DT = DS.Tables[1];)

Comment: @jdweng That [Reset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.reset?view=netframework-4.7.2) call should remove the tables, according to the docs.

Comment: By 'tow' do you mean 'two' ?? Keep two DataSources/DataTables then; atm you clear the 1st one..

Comment: Do I have to create another DataSources/DataTables variables for the second Datagridview ?

Comment: I was looking to make a function that will fill up any Datagrid across the project is that possible?

Comment: You are overwriting the `DataTable` `DT` each time you call `LoadData.`! Example, when you call `LoadData` the first time with `DG1`, its `DataSource` is set to `DT`. On the second call to `LoadData` with `DG2`, it uses the same `DataTable` `DT` as `DG1`. Therefore, the grids should have the same data and subsequent calls will overwrite the previous calls `DT` with the new one.

Comment: You can either make two or more global `DataTable`s OR IMHO a better approach is to create a “NEW” `DataTable` in the `LoadData` method then assign it to the supplied “Grids" `DataSource.` This will remove the global variables altogether and each call to `LoadData` will produce a “NEW” `DataTable` with the correct query. I am betting if you take out the “global” `DT` variable and create it in the `LoadData` method, then it will work as expected.

Comment: _Do I have to create another DataSources/DataTables variables_ Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what a stupid mistake I have made!  all I have to do is to remove the declarations of DataSet and DataTable and put it inside the function and all conflicts are gone thanks (@JohnG, @TaW  and for every member trying to help )

```
public void LoadData(DataGridView Grid, String fields)
    {
        SetConnection();
        sql_con.Open();
        sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
        string CommandText = "select " + fields + " from " + table;
        DB = new SQLiteDataAdapter(CommandText, sql_con);
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        DB.Fill(DS);
        DT = DS.Tables[0];
        Grid.DataSource = DT;
        sql_con.Close();
    }
```